# Using Automapper with Metro Application

Tags: xaml, automapper, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I'm writing a Windows 8 Metro Application using XAML, and am trying to add a reference using NuGet to Automapper, and it's saying its not supported. Is there a way around this? What are the requirements for adding references for Metro apps?

Answer (score 2):

NuGet currently supports installing packages to Metro apps ([work item #1527](http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/1527)) but it does require the package libraries to be compiled for WinRT.

I had a look at Automapper and it only supports .Net 4.0 and Silverlight 4, it would need updated assemblies for WinRT. Note: other packages that don't have assemblies should install fine in Metro app.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of NuGet - *absolutely* no outside or third party assembly can be included in a Metro project that is not first recompiled in WinRT. There is one exception - [Portable Class Libraries](http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2011/12/mango-sample-portable-assemblies.html). But a PCL has many limitations and isn't what you are looking for.